# Trying to send http request from Tomcat servlet to another server, Stuck on HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

Tags: java, apache, http, tomcat, servlets

I try to send request from static function in servlet to remote server,
I use **org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;**

But when I debug it stuck always at creating HttpClient.

I tried running this code from regular JAVA project and it runs and performs as expected but when I try to invoke this method from Tomacat 8, it just doesn't work.

This is the whole JAVA class that suppose to send the image to remote server, I ran this method from regular MAVEN java project and it worked but inside tomcat I get an issue.

This method **locateFileAndUpload** just passes the local file path to one of the following methods (**uploadImageToRemoteServer** or **anotherUpload**).
This method is called from inside a servlet.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class Util {
    public static String UPLOAD_SERVER_LOC = "http://localhost/photopostimg/upload.php";


    /**
     * Get the file name and begin the upload process of the thumbnail and the processed file
     * @param str 
     */
    public static void locateFileAndUpload(String str){
        System.out.println(str);
        try {
            uploadImageToRemoteServer(str);
            //anotherUpload(str);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Util.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static void anotherUpload(String fileLocation) throws IOException {

        String postReceiverUrl = UPLOAD_SERVER_LOC;

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost uploadFile = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);
        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        //builder.addTextBody("field1", "yes", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);

        // This attaches the file to the POST:
        File f = new File(fileLocation);
        builder.addBinaryBody(
            "fileToUpload",
            new FileInputStream(f),
            ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM,
            f.getName()
        );

        HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();
        uploadFile.setEntity(multipart);
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(uploadFile);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        if (resEntity != null) {
            String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
            // you can add an if statement here and do other actions based on the response
            System.out.println(responseStr);
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        }
    }    


    /**
     * Gets Local File location on Tomcat and uploads it to UPLOAD_SERVER_LOC
     * 
     * @param fileLocation
     * @return
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static int uploadImageToRemoteServer(String fileLocation) throws IOException {

        // the URL where the file will be posted
        String postReceiverUrl = UPLOAD_SERVER_LOC;

        // new HttpClient
        //HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        //HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        // post header
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

        //Create File
        File file = new File(fileLocation);
        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);

        //Set up HTTP post
        //MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        MultipartEntityBuilder reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();   
        reqEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        reqEntity.addPart("fileToUpload", fileBody);

        httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity.build());

        // execute HTTP post request
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        if (resEntity != null) {
            String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
            // you can add an if statement here and do other actions based on the response
            System.out.println(responseStr);
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        }
        return 0;

    }

}
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
$maxsize = 20e+6; //set the max upload size in bytes

$error='';
//this will cause the rest of the processing to be skipped
//and the upload form displays
    if (!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']["tmp_name"]) AND
            !isset($error)) {
        $error = "<b>You must upload a file!</b><br /><br />";
        unlink($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
    }else if ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'] > $maxsize AND ($error=='')) {
        $error = "<b>Error, file must be less than $maxsize bytes.</b><br /><br />";
        unlink($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
    }else if ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'] != "image/gif" AND
            $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] != "image/pjpeg" AND
            $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] != "image/jpeg" AND !isset($error)) {
        $error = "<b>You may only upload .gif .png or .jpeg files .</b><br /><br />";
        unlink($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
    }

    if ($error=='') {
        $filename =$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
        //Upload file
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], "img/" . $filename);

        print "<br>Thank you for your upload.";
        //Refresh the page
        exit;
    } else {
        echo ("$error");
    }
?>
```

This method gets path to local file on the Tomcat server and suppose to send it to URL in **UPLOAD_SERVER_LOC** variable.

---

This is where it got stuck:
[image]
[image]

---

This is the Log:

```
14-Jan-2017 09:25:19.894 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [PhotoPost] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@45da3370]) and a value of type [org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors] (value [org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors@7371b780]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
14-Jan-2017 09:25:19.901 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [PhotoPost] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@22c18b15]) and a value of type [org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.Instance] (value [Instance{id=289ec83e-c608-4d92-bfb1-63b75b6eb9e9, referenceCounter=2, store size=12}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
14-Jan-2017 09:25:20.430 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/PhotoPost]
14-Jan-2017 09:25:20.450 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor /Users/pini/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/8.2/apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost/PhotoPost.xml
14-Jan-2017 09:25:23.409 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-6] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
14-Jan-2017 09:25:23.489 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-6] org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer.addServletWithApplication Registering the Jersey servlet application, named api.ApplicationConfig, at the servlet mapping /api/*, with the Application class of the same name.
14-Jan-2017 09:25:24.125 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-6] org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.5.1 2014-01-02 13:43:00...
14-Jan-2017 09:25:24.925 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor /Users/pini/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/8.2/apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost/PhotoPost.xml has finished in 4,474 ms
14-Jan-2017 09:25:24.936 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-10] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/PhotoPost]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
14-Jan-2017 09:25:28.669 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1355)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1341)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1206)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
    at Utility.Util.uploadImageToRemoteServer(Util.java:87)
    at Utility.Util.locateFileAndUpload(Util.java:33)
    at api.PostResource.insertPost(PostResource.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:402)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:349)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1010)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

14-Jan-2017 09:25:54.047 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1355)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1341)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1206)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at Utility.Util.uploadImageToRemoteServer(Util.java:87)
    at Utility.Util.locateFileAndUpload(Util.java:33)
    at api.PostResource.insertPost(PostResource.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:402)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:349)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1010)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

14-Jan-2017 09:25:57.244 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.glassfish.jersey.server.monitoring.RequestEvent$ExceptionCause]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.glassfish.jersey.server.monitoring.RequestEvent$ExceptionCause]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1355)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1341)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1206)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:406)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1010)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have updated this question as requested !

Comment: You forgot to post the stack trace. [edit] your post and add it.

Comment: It didn't crashed it just went to ThreadExecutor and never passes this line : HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault(); , as you can see I tried all three of them and still had no luck. I think it has something to do with tomcat

Comment: _"when I try to invoke this method from Tomcat 8"_ -- show that code... and please read [ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.  You need to provide all the necessary information if you want somebody to help you.

Comment: Is there any way you can simplify your code example? I've never had an HttpClient constructor hang and not give me a stacktrace, so I have to think that it's something to do with your configuration somewhere.

Comment: I can't even understand what the issue is. What does "it stack" mean? Does it mean "it hangs" (i.e. it blocks at this instruction, and never goes to the next one, waiting forever), or does it mean "it throws an exception" (in which case you must post the stack trace of the exception), or something else?

Comment: It never goes to the next one and it's waiting forever, there is no exception or any kind of error

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble using the apache HttpClient, HttpClients from inside tomcat jersey servlet.
I don't exactly can post the issue but it got something to do with ThreadPool and Thread stealing because I ran this task on TaskExecutor and it seems like HttpClient gets blocked when executing it like this.

I ended up using **MultipartUtility** class from here: 
http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/upload-files-by-sending-multipart-request-programmatically

It solved my issue.
I have to point out that using `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` worked for me on regular JAVA and MAVEN project and was really simple to use.

It took me couple of hours to find an alternative but if anyone can make it work with apache's HttpClient and explain what is the exact issue it will be very helpful.